# P-channel FET and CNY17-3 opto isolator

Tags: opto-isolator, fet

Long story short, I want to have a relay turn OFF when the output of a 4017 goes high.

So I installed an opto-isolator, connecting the LED to the output of the 4017, ie "on" until the ouput goes high. That's when I discovered the 4017 will output a voltage to light an LED ... but the off does not connect to ground !

Thus, I installed a p-channel FET wired to ground via a 1.2meg resistor. IN THEORY, (I've yet to reach that stage) the high output of the 4017 into the gate should make the voltage flow low enough to de-energise the relay.

But I still can't get the relay to turn on. I measured the voltage from +ve (12v) to collector of opto, and only got 7.5v. So what to change? The LED resistor? The gate resistor? Add another transitor to the opto emitter with a pair of resistor on opto output?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2flNdzM.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

When switch is closed, it connects 9v to circuit. This switches on LED via FET, and opto transistor turns on relay. The contacts close, supplying AC to the LED driver, which then powers circuit as SW1 is released. (D2 and D4 simply stop 9v reaching LED output drivers, and stops said driver from trying to 'charge' the 9v battery which is at a lower potential. IN THEORY, when the 4017 goes high, it 'affects' the gate, and the output drops to about 2v, so relay loses holding current

(Whilst typing this, have realised the opto may now be 'redundant', and I can wire the relay directly to the 2N3820! But still be interesting to discover what's wrong with current design)

Comment: How do you intend to turn that P-FET on when it’s connected to ground?

Comment: My understanding it that an N channel is tied to positive, with the load between source and neg rail to be on, and the P channel is tied to neg with load between +ve and source to be on. When the latter gate is positive, it switches off.

Comment: I think I might have solved the problem. I'm using a 9v PP3 Zinc battery from Poundland ... not the best battery, and under load of trying to turn on two 30ma relays, (yes, I know, only one shown in diagram) the voltage drops to 8.05v. Time you take off the drop across FET, that comes out at around 7.5v, which is below the minimum for 12v relay. I've also since read that PP3 batteries do not have much mAH, so I will switch to an external 12v supply from 8x AA batts

Comment: Now amended diagram to include second relay - although SW1 and SW2 are actually SW1a and SW1b of a centre off switch

Comment: Please simulate the circuit an check the voltage across M1. Now replace it with an N-channel and try again the same.

Comment: What is the amplitude of the 4017 signal? 5 volts? 9 volts? 12 volts?

Comment: The 4017 is being driven by 12v on pin 16 - as it the rest of the circuit - so I would guess it's got to be approaching the supply line on output. I used a voltmeter in place of relay, (with the P-channel as in diagram) and that's how I found I had 7.5v across relay. When Vcc is applied to gate, it drops to around 2v, which is low enough to de-energise the relay. Now gonna try 2x 9V batts, and a 12v regulator. This should work as batt power is only needed for 5secs whilst the LED driver reaches its 12v output